# Break multiple-line inline element into different elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, background-color

I am trying to achieve visual appearance as it is shown at http://screencast.com/t/bbziM2OGe8 As you see, color applied to the element should be applied to text only, not its whole container. The elements are inline, but as they have multiple lines, background is being applied to a visual block with the same width as the longest line.

The text is dynamic so I can not break it into separate inline elements, so that the last line is a one-line inline element.

I am looking for a JavaScript solution, that could get text metrics and break the dynamic content into separate elements, e.g. span, wrapping each line, something like get total height, line height, calculate number of lines, split text in some way into that number of lines and create elements. The part that I am mostly unsure is how to get what words are shown on each line.

Anyway, even if there is no such script available, please let me know your thoughts and suggestions and I will try to create the script myself.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle that shows what you've tried so far and what problem you need help with.

Comment: Harutyan,have you tried anything?

Comment: I have not tried to create the script yet, looking for suggestions and ideas to start with. @Bill - I have described the problem in the question, please ask here if you need anything more.

Answer (score 0):

If we are given a long string in a text format where each letter has the same width, the problem of correctly breaking the text up into separate lines is trivial.  Assuming then that the font-width depends on the character being displayed, I would suggest writing a script which goes through all the printable characters you are willing to deal with and computing the width for that character.  Then saving this data as an object that can be called like:

```
charLen[character] = length
```

Then write something along the lines of

```
breakText = function(str) {
    var lines = [], maxSize = $('#element').width();

    while( str !== '') { 
        var len = 0, lineText = '';

        while( len <= maxSize ) {
            len += charLen[str.charAt(0)];
            lineText += str.charAt(0);
            str = str.substr(1);
        }

        lines.push(lineText);

    }

    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I understand, it can not handle soft-wraps applied by browser and this could help to break the text without taking words into account, yes? Also, how you would suggest to get dimensions of each character? Maybe create a spam element that has all the same styling, set its text to one character and get its dimensions?